# Unexpected behavior for `respond_with` and `respond_to` in Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm trying to make my actions respond to `:html` and `:json`.

```
class GamesController < ApplicationController

  respond_to :html, :json

  def index
    @games = current_user.games
    respond_with(@games)
  end

end
```

The expected view when I go to `/games` is to see the layout of `views/games/index.haml` and if I go to `/games.json` I should have see the `@games` as JSON data in the broswer.

But what I have is, when I go to `/games.json` I see the source code of `/games` with its layout etc as Json (HTML code with `application/json` in the header"

Comment: a typo? `@players = current_user.games` should be `@games = current_user.games`

Comment: typo here not at my app! (edited)

Comment: views/games/index.haml should be views/games/index.html.haml  I just checked this with an app I made that uses erb and it works fine...Have you tried on an older version of rails?

Comment: @Gazler... Thats right! they might check the extension of the file that would be responded to!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You havve to the extension of the files to tell Rails that i want to render this or not!

`views/games/index.haml should be views/games/index.html.haml I just checked this with an app I made that uses erb and it works fine...Have you tried on an older version of rails?` - via  [Gazler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/219743/gazler)